# Material for inspirational workshop

Tags: inspiration, workshop, cards

I've been searching around for the last few days looking for resources for a inspirational workshop. What I have in mind—and haven't been able to find—in a set of "cards" with different **technologies** (e.g., smartphones, netbooks, iPads) and **web-based services** (e.g., Google Maps, Twitter etc.).

I intend to do a workshop where participants can use these cards as inspiration, i.e., two or three cards can be mixed and matched in order to initiate an inspired, focused brainstorm.

So far, I've found the [Mental Notes](http://getmentalnotes.com/) cards. They seem promising but I would like some technology-specific material, too. Does anybody know whether this is available?

**EDIT**
Yes, I can make these myself and have them printed at a professional photo shop. *But* is there anything to be purchased?

Comment: Cool idea, especially as an addition to Stephen Anderson's Mental Notes! Maybe you should contact him, he might know of other card decks etc. @stephenanderson on twitter.

Comment: @Rahul Will do :)

Comment: Don't think these are what you're looking for, but thought I'd bring them to your attention: http://www.ideo.com/by-ideo/method-cards/?news/ideo-method-cards/

Comment: @DanM Didn't know about those. Looks interesting although, no, this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question on Quora:
[What are some interesting playdecks to get creative/design inspiration?](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-interesting-playdecks-to-get-creative-design-inspiration)

Stephen Anderson posted a long list there of various card decks, grouped by type (creative thinking, psychology/design, design methods, etc) that should be of some use.

You may not find what you're looking for. The reason is that I think your approach may not be the best one: you describe a situation where participants combine technologies and services to initiate a brainstorm. They should be thinking in terms of methods, not tools. For instance, instead of a card saying "Twitter", a card saying "social media", "short messages", or (like Mental Notes) "scarcity" will help initiate the kind of creative brainstorm you're looking for without tainting the result with a specific technology or service. At the brainstorm level, it's important to identify solutions to high level problems - not immediately think in terms of "how can I use Twitter to...".

Comment: Interesting list and some good points on brainstorming, too. I appreciate your answer. I begin to think that the answer to my question is "no, you'll have to create the cards yourself." This is OK - and I see that my strategy is perhaps not optimal. However, I need an easy way to communicate and discuss different technologies and still believe that concrete examples will work in this specific workshop.

Comment: Yes, maybe making the cards yourself would be good. If you do, let us know! I'd love to see them.